# What should I answer in "Do you have other incomes or savings?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am an employee with regular salary in UAE and I'm applying for UK standard visit visa, I don't have other incomes but I have savings that I have saved using my salary so should I choose savings?

Answer (score 2):

As you have savings you should mention those in answer to that question, even when you do not intent to use them for the trip you apply a visa for.

Visa officials will want to know that you can afford the trip, not just have enough money to come but also have some money in the bank (or in an other way) to tide you over if needed.

If you have no other income, you can not chose that.

Answer (score 1):

According to 5.12 in these guidance notes https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589168/VAF1-guidance.pdf you should answer ‘Yes’ and provide details.